# Comparing two data sets for similarity with variable data quality

Tags: dataset, paired-comparisons

I have to compare two data sets for similarity. I'm designing a piece of software which will help improve a drummers accuracy. The software displays a rhythm which the drummer then attempts to play.

The first set of data is the reference set of the timings of beats which have been played.

The second set represents the beats detected by the user's drum playing. If the user played perfectly the two sets of data would be identical.

I need to find a way to score the user's playing as a percentage. i.e. how accurate were their timings.

Ideally I'd just compare the two sets of data one by one however this doesn't work because the beat detection algorithm I'm using isn't 100% reliable. Sometimes it misses a beat and other times it records spurious beats. This means that the two sets of data can be different lengths.

Example:

```
1) Refr: 0.000000
2) Refr: 0.187500
3) Refr: 0.375000
4) Refr: 0.562500
5) Refr: 0.750000
6) Refr: 0.937500
7) Refr: 1.125000
8) Refr: 1.312500

1) Beat: 0.000000
2) Beat: 0.208984
3) Beat: 0.374745
4) Beat: 0.394745
5) Beat: 0.580505
6) Beat: 0.766266
7) Beat: 0.940414
8) Beat: 1.149391
9) Beat: 1.335152
```

Is there a robust statistical technique for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you need to identify which refr-beat pairs minimise some aggregate distance-based penalty, forcing each refr and beat data point to be used only once.  Then you need to make a call on how much extra you penalise for each refr that is left over without a matching beat, and extra beats that don't match to a refr.  This will be based on judgement and subject matter knowledge (eg how bad is it, musically, if they miss a refr completely but are precise with all the others? - only you can tell).